# Can I make Windows 10 upgrade download in parts?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

Windows 10 upgrade download was under progress (61%) then suddenly internet disconnected, now again it started from 0%. Is there anyway we can pause or it automatically resumes when again connected to the internet?

Comment: Use the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from Microsoft instead of waiting for the upgrade.

Comment: I wonder why MS doesn't provide torrents. This works well for LibreOffice ... ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill, they are sort of, [they are sharing bandwidth will other PC's](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2015/07/30/windows-10-steals-your-bandwidth-to-send-other-people-updates/) more like crowdsourcing.

Comment: @Moab Yes, I know about that - for updates only not for iso downloads :/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download an iso file an make an install DVD.

[Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

Microsoft has a great tool for that. You can create an ISO and burn them or a bootable USB-Stick but that could take a lot of time if your USB-Stick is to slow.

Otherwise download the Windows 10 ISO directly and use a download manager.

https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: Are you sure that the media creation tool allows pausing and resuming downloads? This didn't appear to be the case when I tried it.

Comment: Looked everywhere, but the answers were alternative which is now too.

Comment: Then download the ISO directly and use a download manager ;) https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: @Stony The ISO link redirects to the Tool now. Microsoft changed it.

Comment: No ;) when i fill the fields i can download the iso. Test it first ;) and don't make it so complicated.

Comment: Only through win 10 update app is it possible to download in parts, Y/N?

Comment: Which fields are you referring to? What is complicated?

Comment: I don't think so but i can't tell then all my computers downloaded the complete image without restart. So like i sad don't make it so complicated. The ISO is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I saw, if the download fails, it will delete the Windows 10 directory and re-download.  There is a media tool that will do the same thing but doesn't use windows update to gather the files.  You best bet is to get the install files from a computer on a stable connection and transfer to your computer via USB or DVD.  This link will get you what you need.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

I myself downloaded the .ISO, mounted and copied the files out of it on my second Hard Drive and installed from there.

Comment: We live in the time of the Cumulonimbus cloud, it's assumed everyone lives in the big city with high end broadband connections served by Akami networks. They even have 100MBit connections in Eastern "Rural" areas. Heh, restart a 2.7GB download from scratch? No problem!

Comment: I have a download speed of 120 kbps which will take around 10 hours and there is no guarantee of consistency of internet connection because of frequent powercut.

Comment: Why cant downloading in the background continues from the point it stopped?